# Load balancing weighted reports?

Tags: optimization, language-agnostic, load-balancing

I work for a fleet tracking company and this question is specifically about how I plan to do reports. Let me explain our environment. We have 1x Database, 1x Load Distributing process, and 3x Report Processing servers (let's assume these are equal in every way). When a customer requests a report, all the parameters of that report go in the database. I'm currently working on a load distributing app that will take pending reports from the database and delegate them to the 3 report processing servers that build and email the reports. When a server finishes a report (or an error arises), it notifies the load distributing app. Reports can come in all sizes, from 1 days worth of GPS data for 1 vehicles to 3 months of GPS data for hundreds of vehicles.

I can think of a few ways to do the load balancing but I'm not quite happy with them. I could have each server only do 5 reports at most, but 1 server might get 5 small reports while another gets 5 large reports. I could do a "Round Robin" approach and just hand out the reports sequentially across the servers, but this still doesn't protect against overloading any of the servers.

The best idea I think I have right now is to keep a count of how much GPS data is needed by each report (an easy task to do) and as I assign reports to each server I keep a running total for each server. When a server finishes a report (and notifies the load balancer), subtract that report's amount of GPS data from the running total for that server. This way, I could assign the next report to the server with the smallest amount of GPS data to work with. I could also set a max so that a server cannot get over worked (the problem that is causing us to refactor our whole reports process to begin with). If there are more reports when all servers hit their max, it can just queue them up and attempt them later when the servers finish a few of their reports.

I'm not convinced it's the best approach for finishing reports as quickly as possible. These are just the best I have come up with so far.

How can I optimize my approach to load balancing reports of different sizes across multiple servers?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have only one major table which you select data from, then I would configure one server to do all the big reports first and leave the other two to do smallest to largest. Otherwise big reports might never get done.

For the smaller reports, you want to try, in the absence of anything better, to have them try and run 'similar' reports, meaning those that cluster around similar values in the index mainly used. For example if a server has just completed a report for June 2011, then the next best report to run is same period, not jumping to November 2012. This is dependent on the actual table though, but I am presuming you have lots of date ordered data comprising the bulk of the selection. All you are really trying to do is group reports that are likely to reuse cached indexes/etc as this should give best throughput.

I have a similar scheduling problem, and any queries that are directed to major tables go one server (slow queue) and anything else goes to another ( fast queue), with some exceptions for special cases.